How do I resolve this OpenCV Installation error
I was trying to install OpenCV in my project, I followed the tutorial here.
I'm running a Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS on a WSL on Windows 10.
The problem I'm encountering is during the make command in the build directory, here's the cropped output:
[ 21%] Built target opencv_highgui_plugins
[ 21%] Built target opencv_dnn_plugins
[ 21%] Built target opencv_videoio_plugins
[ 21%] Built target ittnotify
[ 21%] Built target ippiw
[ 21%] Built target libopenjp2
[ 21%] Built target ade
[ 21%] Built target libwebp
[ 21%] Built target libprotobuf
[ 21%] Built target IlmImf
[ 21%] Building CXX object modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/src/parallel_impl.cpp.o
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include/immintrin.h:43,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include/x86intrin.h:32,
                 from /home/andrea/Code/AI/esercitazione4-23-24/opencv/modules/core/src/parallel_impl.cpp:43:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include/xsaveintrin.h:3:10: error: stray ‘\’ in program
    3 |        */\m* */\M*
      |          ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include/xsaveintrin.h:3:16: error: stray ‘\’ in program
    3 |        */\m* */\M*
      |                ^
...
      |          ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include/xsaveoptintrin.h:50:43: error: missing terminating " character
   50 | |/\Z| \Z \Z ignore differences in Unicode "combi
      |                                           ^~~~~~
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include/immintrin.h:47,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include/x86intrin.h:32,
                 from /home/andrea/Code/AI/esercitazione4-23-24/opencv/modules/core/src/parallel_impl.cpp:43:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include/xsavesintrin.h:5:10: error: stray ‘\’ in program
    5 |        */\+*
      |          ^
...
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include/xsavesintrin.h:58:13: error: stray ‘@’ in program
   58 |  foo\(bar\)\@=foo nothing
      |             ^
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include/immintrin.h:49,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include/x86intrin.h:32,
                 from /home/andrea/Code/AI/esercitazione4-23-24/opencv/modules/core/src/parallel_impl.cpp:43:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include/xsavecintrin.h:1:9: error: missing terminating ' character
    1 | skeyword'.
      |         ^~
...
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include/xsavecintrin.h:42:24: error: stray ‘\’ in program
   42 |   or  concat \& concat \& concat
      |                        ^
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include/immintrin.h:51,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include/x86intrin.h:32,
                 from /home/andrea/Code/AI/esercitazione4-23-24/opencv/modules/core/src/parallel_impl.cpp:43:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include/avxintrin.h:11:24: error: missing terminating ' character
   11 | Long-time Vim users won't use menus much.  But the power is in adding your own
      |                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
...
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include/avxintrin.h:1451:2: error: #endif without #if
 1451 | #endif /* _AVXINTRIN_H_INCLUDED */
      |  ^~~~~
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include/immintrin.h:85,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include/x86intrin.h:32,
                 from /home/andrea/Code/AI/esercitazione4-23-24/opencv/modules/core/src/parallel_impl.cpp:43:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include/avx512vpopcntdqintrin.h:1:4: error: stray ‘`’ in program
    1 | -| `
      |    ^
...
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include/avx512vpopcntdqvlintrin.h:81:15: error: missing terminating " character
   81 | copied to the "* register.
      |               ^~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include/immintrin.h:103,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include/x86intrin.h:32,
                 from /home/andrea/Code/AI/esercitazione4-23-24/opencv/modules/core/src/parallel_impl.cpp:43:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include/bmiintrin.h:25:22: error: missing terminating ' character
   25 | is the window manager's job.  But if compiled with GTK+ 2 support, Vim helps
      |                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
...
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include/bmiintrin.h:143:2: error: #endif without #if
  143 | #endif /* _BMIINTRIN_H_INCLUDED */
      |  ^~~~~
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include/immintrin.h:105,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include/x86intrin.h:32,
                 from /home/andrea/Code/AI/esercitazione4-23-24/opencv/modules/core/src/parallel_impl.cpp:43:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include/bmi2intrin.h:25:9: error: missing terminating ' character
   25 | Since it's a CSS, they can be rewritten using shorthand: >
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
...
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include/bmi2intrin.h:109:5: error: missing terminating ' character
  109 | that's not available in the plain GTK+ GUI:  Interaction with the session
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include/immintrin.h:109,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include/x86intrin.h:32,
                 from /home/andrea/Code/AI/esercitazione4-23-24/opencv/modules/core/src/parallel_impl.cpp:43:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include/f16cintrin.h:1:33: error: too many decimal points in number
    1 | *if_ole.txt*    For Vim version 8.1.  Last change: 2019 May 05
      |                                 ^~~~
...
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include/f16cintrin.h:89:30: error: missing terminating ' character
   89 |  Twelve = Vim.Eval("6 + 6")  ' Note this is a STRING
      |                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include/immintrin.h:113,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include/x86intrin.h:32,
                 from /home/andrea/Code/AI/esercitazione4-23-24/opencv/modules/core/src/parallel_impl.cpp:43:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include/xtestintrin.h:5:2: error: stray ‘\’ in program
    5 |  \(an\_s\+\)\@<=file "file" after "an" and white space or an
      |  ^
...
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include/xtestintrin.h:34:6: error: stray ‘@’ in program
   34 |   /<\@1<=span
      |      ^
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include/immintrin.h:43,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include/x86intrin.h:32,
                 from /home/andrea/Code/AI/esercitazione4-23-24/opencv/modules/core/src/parallel_impl.cpp:43:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include/xsaveintrin.h:1:1: error: ‘cter’ does not name a type
    1 | cter is taken literally or not depends on the 'magic' option and the
      | ^~~~
make[2]: *** [modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/build.make:999: modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/src/parallel_impl.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1703: modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:166: all] Error 2

There's also the full version here, I can't paste it entirely here since it's too long.
I tried sudo update and sudo upgrade, I tried to update the WSL, to restart it, to make clean and then retry.
I also tried to comment these lines in the CMakeLists in opencv/modules/core:
ocv_add_dispatched_file_force_all(test_intrin128 TEST SSE2 SSE3 SSSE3 SSE4_1 SSE4_2 AVX FP16 AVX2 AVX512_SKX)
ocv_add_dispatched_file_force_all(test_intrin256 TEST AVX2 AVX512_SKX LASX)
ocv_add_dispatched_file_force_all(test_intrin512 TEST AVX512_SKX)

but the same error pops up, and here's the CMakeLists.

Sharing a docs document is a first I must say. Why don't you just post the error message in your Question? Please have a look at how to ask. Please provide us with your CMakeLists.txt.

Sorry, you edited your post and did exactly the same thing again. Don't post links or images in your question. StackOverflow have perfect support for adding code and error message in the question. You have my downvote now.

I used a docs link because the error is too long to be pasted in the question, also you are right about not providing the CMakeLists, I added the GitHub repository of OpenCV I'm using.

The error message is the same error repeated countless times, you really do not need to include them all..

You are right, I cropped it to remove the duplicate errors

I really misunderstood your question completely. We do not need the CMakeLists.txt from OpenCV, and you really should NOT touch it.

Have you made sure to install all Required Packages?

I did, I ran the exactly same commands wrote in the tutorial, I this case:
[compiler] sudo apt-get install build-essential
[required] sudo apt-get install cmake git libgtk2.0-dev pkg-config libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libswscale-dev
[optional] sudo apt-get install python-dev python-numpy libtbb2 libtbb-dev libjpeg-dev libpng-dev libtiff-dev libjasper-dev libdc1394-22-dev


Also, may I ask why you are using such an old version of OpenCV?

Our professor provided us with the tutorial link for the version 3.4.20

Is the task itself to install OpenCV from sources?

The task is to install OpenCV in the project/homework directory using the tutorial or the commands provided by the professor (they are the same as the tutorial), and then use it in the project/homework

I could provide you with the homework repository but it's not in english

I just built OpenCV 3.4.2 from sources using the tutorial you linked without issue. Did you download the sources or clone the repository?

I cloned it, thank you for your time btw

No problem, did you make sure to check out the right branch after cloning it? It default to 4.x otherwise.

I did not actually, let me try.
Like this right: git -C opencv checkout 3.4 ?

Just navigate to the directory and call git checkout 3.4.

Negative, removed the build folder, checked out the 3.4 branch, called cmake and then sudo make in the build dir but the error is still there

And this is the CMake command you called? cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local ..

Affirmative, I could share with you the console output when I call cmake if you need

Could you please try callling sudo apt-get install build-essential once more and then try again?

Done, it says build-essential is already the newest version (12.8ubuntu1.1)
And it still doesn't work.

At this point I'm thinking of installing a newer version anyway hoping it will work with the homework

It definitely would make it easier. You can literally install it using a one-liner: sudo apt install libopencv-dev python3-opencv.

Now running the homework compile script it detects OpenCV -.-
It was way easier this way D:
Well thank you so much for your help, I hope everything will work just fine this way

Feel free to give my answer an upvote and mark it as solution. I would appreciate the extra reputation.

Instead of installing it from source you could just install it using:
sudo apt install libopencv-dev python3-opencv

